# Strip all whitespace in text except actual single space

Tags: python, regex

How would I do this in python3?

```
The            quick     brown                fox jumps over the  lazy dog.
```

to...

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Where the above quote is a string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `regex` here. You can achieve what you want like this ways:

```
a = "The            quick     brown                fox jumps over the  lazy dog."
final = " ".join(a.split())
print(final)
```

Output:

```
'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
```